# I/O error on writing files - GCSfuse in GKE

Tags: gcsfuse

I am trying to mount and use googleBucket in multiple pods in kubernetes "cluster" for our use case. (GFS and NFS are viable solutions but not for us)

I am able to mount the bucket and can see the contents of the bucket but when I am trying to write to it by touching a file or creating a directory it is giving me following error:

```
root@bucket-5f88fd5fd7-j84mg:/mnt# touch test
touch: cannot touch 'test': Input/output error
```

I know there is some permission issue. Do I need to install gcloud sdks too ? or is there some environment variable I can set to get rid of this error. 
I read somewhere we can use "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS" but how to use this I was not clear.

Comment: You can run gcsfuse with the `--foreground` flag to see what the underlying error is. If it's persistent, then it's very likely a permissions problem with your credentials.

Answer (score 0):

You can run gcsfuse with the --foreground flag to see what the underlying error is. If it's persistent, then it's very likely a permissions problem with your credentials.